# integrity constraint violation and column field is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

[Tables need to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meGlz.png)

I want to update target_dir, source_dir, login_name, password, backup_schedule, backup_time in table host and backup_schedule and backup_time in table view_page where host.host = view_page.host. 
Whenever I am using update statement it is showing Violation in integrity constraint and column field is ambiguous.

Comment: Please share table structures for both the tables, your update statement and exact error message that is generated.

Comment: please click on the hyperlink "Tables need to be updated" to get the table structure.

Comment: Please share your update statement also and exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: "update host inner join view_page on host.host = view_page.host set target_dir=?, source_dir=?, login_name=?, password=?, backup_schedule=?, backup_time=? where host.host = view_page.host and host=?" This is the update statement I am using. "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'backup_schedule' in filed list is ambiguous"

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to affect to them, so I'll just put "value".

```
UPDATE host, view_page
SET host.target_dir = value, host.source_dur = value, host.login_name = value, host.password = value, host.backup_schedule = value, host.backup_time = value,view_page.backup_schedule = value, view_page.backup_time = value 
WHERE host.host = view_page.host;
```

Is that what you wanted ? (Did not test, but it should work.)